# Get logged on user's email address via LDAP: supply password to search LDAP or not?

Tags: authentication, asp-classic, vbscript, ldap, basic-authentication

I'm writing a VBScript file to get the current logged in user's name and email address. Some solutions require a username/password hard-coded to perform an LDAP search, while others don't.

What are the pros/cons of each method?

**Option 1: No LDAP username/password** [source](http://ss64.com/vb/syntax-userinfo.html)

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName) ' Currently logged in User
Response.Write("Email: " & objUser.mail)
```

**Option 2: Hard-coded LDAP username/password** [source](https://support.zendesk.com/entries/21860832-configure-zendesk-for-your-active-directory-microsoft-environment)

```
strUsername = split(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"),"\")(1)

Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

sDomainContainer = rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
oConn.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"
oConn.properties("user id") = sLdapReaderUsername
oConn.properties("password") = sLdapReaderPassword
oConn.Open "ADs Provider"

sQuery = "<LDAP://" & sDomainContainer & ">;(sAMAccountName=" & strUsername & ");adspath,mail,displayName,sAMAccountName;subtree"
Set userRS = oConn.Execute(sQuery)

If NOT userRS.EOF AND NOT err Then Response.Write(userRS("mail"))
```

Comment: Maybe "No password" is really "Single sign-on" or "Impersonation". How  is the user authenticated ? You have the basic-authentication tag. Please confirm that your ASP application uses the built-in IIS basic-auth method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how your LDAP server is configured. Usually they are configured to allow an anonymous search for a user that doesn't access any private attributes, e.g. just returns the DN with no attributes at all. Then you 'bind' using that DN and the password, and that establishes authentication; then you can access all your own (the user's) attributes, say 'Hi Jim', etc.

Comment: I had a hunch it's to do with the double hop problem and was really looking for someone to confirm that. For example, running Option 1 on a domain controller works via IIS, but running it on another server on the domain will not work, presumably due to the double hop problem.

Comment: In my experience, anynomous search are usually *disabled* by default. It's like that in ActiveDirectory and AD-LDS, as well as most other directory I've worked with (Oracle OID configured for EUS would be the exception).